# API ok from localhost but failed with Ajax - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, ajax, flask, connection-refused

I have a very minimal API (let's call it api.py) using Flask :

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restx import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
api = Api(app)


@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):
        def get(self):
                return {"hello" : "world"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=5000)
}`
```

I then run : python3 api.py, no error
On another command line, I then query the API

```
curl http://localhost:5000/hello
```

which give me the right answer : {"hello": "world"}
On its side, the Flask App says : 127.0.0.1 - - [21/May/2020 22:55:38] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Which seems ok to me

I then build a JS / Ajax Query to query the API from a WebPage :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:5000/hello"
    , type: "GET"
    , contentType: "application/json"
    , dataType: "json"
    , success: function(data) {
         console.log(data)
    }
})
```

When I access the Web Page that fires the Ajax call, I get the following error message :
GET http://localhost:5000/hello net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I understand that is a CORS issue. The problem is that I did test ALL the tricks from SO and other help forums with no success...
I did try :

```
from flask_cors import CORS
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=False)
@cross-origin
...
```

Nothing works, I still have this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Thanks for any help on that subject, as I am loosing my head with that problem...

Comment: Dumb question, but is the front end really going to be cross origin? You do not need CORS if you're using ajax calls on pages you're rendering.

Comment: No, you are right, API and index.html (served by Nginx) are on the same resource. I just don't get the meaning of this ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED... And I don't have any kind of firewall that would block my port 5000 :-)

Comment: tail the nginx error log to see what error code is being thrown. Possibly another dumb question, but is your browser on the nginx server or is your code pointing to your personal localhost when you mean to point to the server IP of nginx?

Comment: /var/log/nginx/error.log is empty ! Regarding global architecture : Nginx / Flask API / HTML page are located on a AWS EC2 instance. I just query the web page from my local computer

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call shouldn't be pointing to localhost. Replace it with the URL of the EC2 instance.

Comment: The EC2 instance doesn't have port 5000 open. So, setting the external address of the Ajax call to the URL of the EC2 instance will not work. If I set it to local IP (10.0.0.206), I have the following error display after few seconds : GET http://10.0.0.206:5000/hello net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: So once again, I did not get why doing a curl http://localhost:5000/hello or curl http://10.0.0.206:5000 is perfectly working and why it does not work using Ajax... I'm going to cry :-(

Comment: I'm guessing that your curl to localhost and the other IP are going to your LOCAL development instance and THAT would be a CORS request if done via ajax when rendered from the nginx server. So, you're getting responses from the wrong server. Nginx shouldn't be serving over 5000, that's python flask development server port. Nginx should be port 80 or 443

Comment: My Nginx is not serving anything on port 5000. It is configured to only answer port 80 (not even 443, for the moment). I just did a : sudo systemctl stop nginx and a curl http://localhost:5000/hello is perfectly working. Thus, I can say that it is Flask server that respond to this query, not the Nginx server

Comment: OK, that's your problem. You are not calling your nginx server correctly.

Comment: Uhhhh... don't see what you mean, here.. Nginx is answering when I request http://ip_of_ec2_instance:80 and display properly my web page. The problem is that when I fired the Ajax call, I've got the previous explained error (ERR_CONNECTION_ERROR or TIMEOUT). I don't see how I could "call nginx server correctly" ??

Answer (score 0):

No need to configure Nginx to listen on your app's port for this task. Or exposing this port outside on the remote host.

But yes, for *remote server setup* ajax call shouldn't be pointing to the localhost. You need to update it to the url you see in the browser. So either machine IP or a DNS.

While for *local machine* debugging you could try `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.

The second part of making this work is to deal with CORS:

- for remote server CORS should be enabled both in the app (as middleware) and in the preflight request (see how to allow CORS for OPTIONS requests);
- for local machine I would recommend disabling CORS by running the browser in disabled security mode (like `disable-web-security` flag for Chrome etc.).